# Book about a girl who is a thief and learns to transform into a puma or cougar

Tags: story-identification, books

It’s a book with a girl in a kingdom. She has no family but is drawn to animals. She is a thief but later on learns how to transform into a puma or a cougar or some type of cat. She finds a tribe of people like her. I believe it has a purple cover with a puma styled door knocker. I read it about 8 or 9 years ago.

Comment: Daughter of Dusk by Livia Blackburne ... isn't it. It is about an orphan girl who is a thief and discovers she has connections to a group of feline shape-shifters. And it was published in 2015, and the cover is dark purple. BUT it has a pawprint on the cover, not a door knocker, and the plot summaries I've seen say nothing about whether she herself actually morphs.

Comment: @nebogipfel Sounds close enough to provide an answer.

Comment: If so, it would be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/246862/book-with-a-girl-werecat-who-works-for-the-government/246867#246867

Comment: Thanks, so I proposed it anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I agree with nebogipfel that this is the Midnight Thief series by Livia Blackburne, but the book you remember is the first book of the series [Midnight Thief](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17566814-midnight-thief).

[image: Midnight Thief]

> Growing up on Forge’s streets has taught Kyra how to stretch a coin. And when that’s not enough, her uncanny ability to scale walls and bypass guards helps her take what she needs.
>
> But when the leader of the Assassins Guild offers Kyra a lucrative job, she hesitates. She knows how to get by on her own, and she’s not sure she wants to play by his rules. But he’s persistent—and darkly attractive—and Kyra can’t quite resist his pull.
>
> Tristam of Brancel is a young Palace knight on a mission. After his best friend is brutally murdered by Demon Riders, a clan of vicious warriors who ride bloodthirsty wildcats, Tristam vows to take them down. But as his investigation deepens, he finds his efforts thwarted by a talented thief, one who sneaks past Palace defenses with uncanny ease.
>
> When a fateful raid throws Kyra and Tristam together, the two enemies realize that their best chance at survival—and vengeance—might be to join forces. And as their loyalties are tested to the breaking point, they learn a startling secret about Kyra’s past that threatens to reshape both their lives.

It has the cover you remember, and as you remembered Kyra meets the other shape shifters when a shapeshifter rescues her after she is injured. She discovers their race is called the *Makvani*.

> Beside her, the cat woman retied her tunic. “Answer me first. Where are you from? Who sired you?”
>
> “Who sired me?” Kyra said, shrinking away. “I’m an orphan.”
>
> “You were raised by humans, then.”
>
> “What?”
>
> The cat woman stepped back again, shaking her head in disbelief. She raised her hand to her mouth and sank her teeth into her own palm. Kyra gasped. When the woman held out her hand again, it was dotted with specks of blood.
>
> “Smell it.”
>
> Kyra flinched away, but the woman kept her hand in front of Kyra’s face. It smelled like blood. Too much like the stuff of her nightmares for comfort. Obviously frustrated by Kyra’s blank expression, the woman scooped up Kyra’s bloody bandages and thrust them under her nose.
>
> “Can you not tell? Even in your skin, you can smell our blood.”
>
> Kyra noticed it then. There was a common element, a musky smell that made her think of long hunts through the forest. No, that was just her imagination running wild. For all she knew, everybody’s blood smelled like that.
>
> Seeing Kyra’s expression, the woman pulled back. “Our blood runs through your veins. What is your name?”
>
> “Kyra.” The word came out through numb lips.
>
> The woman knelt down and took Kyra’s hands. “Kyra. My name is Pashla,” she said. “I, like you, am a daughter of the Makvani.”

Comment: Thank you so much! This is the one I’ve been looking for, for about a week. I remember liking the series and wanted to read it again. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Well, [Daughter of Dusk](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/22678141-daughter-of-dusk) by Livia Blackburne has some of the characteristics. It is about an orphan girl who is a thief and discovers she has connections to a group of feline shape-shifters. And it was published in 2015, and the cover is dark purple. BUT it has a pawprint on the cover, not a door knocker, and the plot summaries I've seen say nothing about whether she herself actually morphs.

[image]